# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map Retrofit 2 Post Request with Query Params

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to make a post request using retrofit 2.3.0. Here it is:

```
@POST("/oscarapi/basket/add-product/")
    Call<Basket> addItemToBasket(@Query("area_id") int areaId,@Body HashMap<String, Object> body);
```

But it straightaway throws an error saying :

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

This error is coming only when I updated the retrofit version to the latest one in gradle. Also on Android 7.0 and above it works fine but on Android 6.0 its showing this error. If I remove the query param call goes through.

Issue is definitely with @Query. is there another way to pass query params for post requests? because it expects only Map parameter which would be the body for post request. Its not recognising the @Query or @QueryMap attributes.

I am calling this method like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
int id = mMenuItem.id;
if (mMenuItem.variants != null && mMenuItem.variants.size() > 0) {
    id = mMenuItem.variants.get(mHolder.variantSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).id;
}

body.put("url", Constant.PRODUCT_URL + id + "/");
body.put("quantity", Integer.parseInt(mHolder.numberView.getText().toString()));
body.put("instructions", mHolder.instructions.getText().toString());

List<OptionModel> options = getOptions();
if (options.size() > 0)
    body.put("options", options);
Api.getInstance().getEndPoint()
    .addItemToBasket(PreferenceUtils.getAreaId(getActivity()), 
     body).enqueue(new Callback<Basket>() {
```

body is of type HashMap & getAreadId returns an integer value.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Update your question with postman success image and code?

Comment: Thanks for responding guys. This is the way I am calling this method.

Comment: @R2R Also its not even making the API call. It fails before making API call.

Comment: @HassanImtiaz can you share complete API implementation code?

Comment: This was a very strange issue. When I create apk then code runs just fine. But it only happened when I directly installed app on device through android studio.